# Escape sequence octal notation not working as expected

Tags: java

```
class A {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char c= '\777';
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

This is giving compile error (running on Java 8 compiler).

octal notation for escape sequence is of the format '\xxx' but in the above case its not working, char c='\077' is working.

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Because `777` is not octal?

Answer (score 2):

The [JLS, Section 3.10.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6), "Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals", states that an octal `char` literal can be up to 3 octal digits, and if there are 3, then the first one is limited to 0-3.

> ```
> OctalEscape:
> \ OctalDigit 
> \ OctalDigit OctalDigit 
> \ ZeroToThree OctalDigit OctalDigit 
>
> OctalDigit:
> (one of) 
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
>
> ZeroToThree:
> (one of) 
> 0 1 2 3
> ```

The max `\377` is 255 in decimal, so it looks like this is done so that the value fits in one (unsigned) byte.

Comment: That applies to octal *numerals*, which is not the same as a character literal octal escape value, which is define in section [3.10.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6), and does not have to start with a `0` digit.

Answer (score 2):

Because the octal escape sequence can only specify 1-byte character values and octal `777` is decimal `511`, i.e. outside the range of a 1-byte value.

As the Java Language Specification [3.10.6. Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) says it:

> Octal escapes are provided for **compatibility with C**, but can express only Unicode values `\u0000` through `\u00FF`, so **Unicode escapes are usually preferred**.

The full specification of an octal escape is:

> ```
> OctalEscape:
>   \ OctalDigit
>   \ OctalDigit OctalDigit
>   \ ZeroToThree OctalDigit OctalDigit
>
> OctalDigit:
>   (one of)
>   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
>
> ZeroToThree:
>   (one of)
>   0 1 2 3
> ```

As you can see, the max allowed octal number is `377`.

Answer (score 1):

Octal characters can go from `0` to `377` (that is in Hex: `0x00` to `0xFF`).

In order to go beyond that, you will need to use the `\uXXXX` notation which represents the hexadecimal based in Unicode.

The Java documentation regarding `Character` is pretty [lengthy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)  and offers a lot of information regarding this subject.

For your particular example, I think you want to do something like:

```
public  class A {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char c= '\u0777';
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```